# How can I make the indicator function faster or smarter in python?

Tags: python, indicator

I am trying to replicate a ML paper in python. The only thing that I need is to do better the indicator function what is: Given a set F, is featture fi in it ? The result should be 1 or 0. I am working with a matrix 700 samples x 8 features. And I want to check if a feature is in the set F. Here are my code. It works, but very slowly.
Let X be the full matrix and X[:,i]=feat. F can be an empty set or contain features of X

```
def I (feat,F):

  respuesta=[]
  for i in F:
         respuesta.append(np.all(i==feat))

  if np.any(respuesta)==True:

         result=1
  elif np.any(respuesta)==False:
         result=0
  else:
         raise ValueError('something hapens')

  return(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

A first obvious optimization would be to avoid calling `np.any(respuesta)` twice... This:

```
if np.any(respuesta)==True:
   result=1
elif np.any(respuesta)==False:
   result=0
return result
```

can be replaced by

```
return np.any(respuesta)
```

But even then this requires building the whole `respuesta` list for no good reason since one single valid result is enough. So you can just return True on the first valid result:

```
def I (feat,F):
  for i in F:
     if np.all(i==feat):
         return True
  return False
```

There might be better solutions, but it's hard to tell without knowing what `F`, `i` and `feat` really are.

Comment: F is a list ( a set mathematically) i is the feature i in the set and feat is feature.

Comment: That doesn't explain what is a "feature".

Comment: a feature vector, from some ML model, like the house prices in your town.